# how to junit test a controller?

Tags: mockito, resttemplate, junit5

I have two classes Feature and FeatureLocation in different package and I want to do junit test on getFeatureLocation in FeatureLocation class.

```java
public class Feature {
    public static String getfeature(String url, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        String xml = "\"feature\": 1";
        String json = restTemplate.postForObject(url, xml, String.class);
        return json;
    }
}

public class FeatureLocation{
    public String getFeatureLocation(){
       Feature feature = new Feature();
       return feature.getfeature("http:test",new RestTemplate())
    }
}
```

The test I did as below:

```java
String xml = "\"feature\": 1";
RestTemplate restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);
Feature feature = mock(Feature.class);

Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject("http:test", xml, String.class))
       .thenReturn("testPass");

Mockito.when(feature.getFeature("http:test", restTemplate)).thenReturn("test")
```

my problem is when I mock the feature.getFeature, it doesn't return "test". It also could not see the mock I have for the restTemplate.

Comment: Mockito is not able to mock a object that is created inside a method (`new Feature()`). Either pass feature from the outside (to the constructor or the method) or use `PowerMockito` instead.

Comment: Same for `new RestTemplate()`. I'll made an edit request for your question, please post properly formatted and compilable java code next time.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do this `Feature feature = mock(Feature.class);`, it won't help because every time you call `getFeatureLocation` method, you are creating a new object of `Feature` and `RestTemplate` i.e.

`Feature feature = new Feature();`
and
`feature.getfeature("http:test", new RestTemplate())`

I would suggest you to inject `Feature` and `RestTemplate`in `FeatureLocation`. For example -

```
public class FeatureLocation {

    private Feature feature;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public FeatureLocation(Feature feature, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.feature = feature;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String getFeatureLocation(){
       return feature.getfeature("http:test", restTemplate);
    }
}
```

And in the test, you can mock the `Feature` as you are already doing and the inject it into `FeatureLocation`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You want to remove the `static` from the `getfeature`-method as well else mockito won't be able to handle it.

Comment: thanks for the helps, but for my code, I cannot remove the static from getfeature method. Is there a way to mock static method?